# Issue with "Create a copy or Field" in Kettle - Pentaho

Tags: calculator, pentaho, kettle

I'm facing this strange result with pentaho and a "Calculator" step. I've got this flow.

[image]

I need to copy one of the column coming from the 'Setting - Location' input step. So I use a calculator (I need to use it in another transformation). However when I see the result I'am getting this.

[image]

'Location' is the columns that should be equal to 'City code'.

What could be happening?

Regards

Comment: Check your data types. You may have the field defined with the wrong type upstream.

Comment: Hi @nsousa. All of them are defined as String. I made another test using a data grid instead a csv input and it works with out any problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to turn off the 'Lazy Conversion' feature in the csv input step in order to fix this issue.